# How to apply i18n on whole website by a single click in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, internationalization

Is it possible to apply Struts 2 Internationalization (i18n) for changing language from English to Hindi on whole web pages of website by single click?

If it is possible then how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Hi @Andrea Ligios,  please elaborate how can I resolve this problem.....?

Comment: @AleksandrM Why so rude?

Comment: @RomanC Rude? It was the polite one of the two. :)

Comment: @AleksandrM I have already posted this link in my answer, and previous answer, you can upvote both :)

Answer (score 1):

> > ## The framework is internationalized.
>
> You need to add the corresponding to each locale resource bundles for
>   the localized messages that you display via the struts tags. Use
>   `text` tag or `getText()` to retrieve a message in the UI.
>
> The browser language is passed with the HTTP request and framework
>   create a locale corresponding to the browser settings. Switching
>   locale performed via passing a special parameter `request_locale` to
>   `i18n` interceptor that should be on your stack.
>
> You can also configure this interceptor to accept user-defined
>   parameters.
>
> Normally switching to a locale persist for the session of the user.
>   So, you don't have to pass a parameter each time on every request, but
>   this case is also supported if needed. See how could you achieve all
>   of the above using [localization](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/localization.html).

Comment: Hi Roman C, My problem is if my website have total 20 pages then by using internationalized framework I want to change text local for all pages by click on a tab which is on header.

Comment: Please read this answer, it has a link that you can follow to read more about you problem and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @RomanC , it is possible to do that, you need to have the `i18n` interceptor in your package.

After that you need your jsp page `submit` a form with `request_locale` in it, or call an action with `request_locale` in its parameters . For example, if you want to do it with `select` you can use below:

```
<s:form id="langselect" action="locale-manager" namespace="/common">
        <s:select name="request_locale" headerKey="-1"
                headerValue="Language" 
                list="#{'en_US':'English', 'fa_IR':'فارسی','ar_SA':'العربية','zh_CN':'中国的'}"
                onchange="forms['langselect'].submit()" />
</s:form>
```

You form action needs nothing to do about changing the locale at all, as the interceptor will do all the job for you.

Changing the locale will change all your 20 pages at once, of course as soon as you reload your pages. So if you want to do it with `tab` you need to reload your new pages (for example with ajax) or reload your total site to get localized jsp from struts.